# Am I using Grand Central Dispatch correctly?

Tags: c++, grand-central-dispatch

I have a procedure that calculates the outcome of a game by random sample; it is passed a number of iterations, runs a loop of that size storing the outcomes in a local variable (subHits), then after the loop is done, adds the totals from the local variables into a class level member variable (m_Hits), to wit:

```
void Game::LogOutcomes(long periodSize) {
    int subHits[11];
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        subHits[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int iters = 0; iters < periodSize; ++iters) {
        // ... snipped out code calculating rankIndex by random sample.
        ++subHits[rankIndex];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        m_Hits[i] += subHits[i];
    }
}
```

.. of course, it uses a local variable as temporary storage for purposes of running the procedure in parallel, which I invoke with:

```
dispatch_queue_t globalQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_apply(m_BatchSize / m_PeriodSize, globalQ, ^(size_t periodCount) {
    LogBonusWager(m_PeriodSize);
});
```

.. and it seems to work perfectly (all results are sufficiently close to statistically expected value).  I can't help but think there's something wrong, because nowhere am I specifically 'locking' the class level variable when updating it with the contents of the local variable, and that I'm getting the right results through sheer good fortune.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting lucky. You should either have a dedicated (serial) queue for updating the shared state, or use OSAtomicAddSize to add to it. Without this you'll be losing updates occasionally.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this (as you can tell), so how would I go about implementing having a serial queue to update the shared state?

Comment: `dispatch_queue_t mHitsGuard = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.mHitsUpdateQueue", 0); 

...

dispatch_async(mHitsGuard, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        m_Hits[i] += subHits[i];
    }
}`

Comment: Apparently I can figure out GCD fine but can't for the life of me remember how stack overflow comment formatting works. >.<

Comment: I tried that, and got some pretty arcane errors.. it thought it was redefining the variable i from earlier in the loop, and if I change the variable to j, it gave me other arcane errors.. finally, I had to change subHits from an int[11] to a vector<int>.. will post more detail shortly on these errors, but for now, just wanted to say that I did a little work around (put the update into a procedure and called the procedure on dispatch_async(mHitsGuard, ^{ LogSubHits(subHits); }); and it works like a charm!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay.. when I entered the code as is, I got:

    'i' is not a static member of 'class', 
    Name lookup of 'i' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping, 
    increment of read-only variable 'i' errors.. and when using the int[11] instead of the vector<int>, I got "cannot access copied-in variable of array type inside block".. I'm guessing that this GCD still needs a little ironing out?

Comment: That's a blocks/compiler thing, not a GCD thing (GCD is the library, blocks are the language feature). You'll need to declare the array __block.